# Second Order Nonlinear ODE Missing a Constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a closed form solution to this equation:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac1{y^2}$$
I have found that all the functions of the form:
$$y=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{36}*(x-c)^\frac2 3}2$$
will satisfy the equation, but shouldn't there be another constant somewhere in there?

Comment: The constant in front appears (only) when the ODE is linear, and here its clearly not the case.

Comment: You mean the $-\frac{\sqrt[3]{36}}2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You may write $$ y'' y' = \frac{1}{y^2}y'$$ and integrate.
There is indeed another constant of integration (but with non-linear dependency).

Comment: Would I then use the reduction of order method or something else? Posting the link just in case anyone calls it something different. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx

Comment: I don't really find the present problem in that link. But $(y' ^2)' = 2 y'y''$ and $(1/y)'=-y'/y^2$ should probably help you. I think, however, that in general you will not be able to find an explicit solution of $y$ as a function of $x$ (but you may obtain $x$ as a function of $y$. The expression is rather nasty (except for the case you found!) so probably of little practical use.

Comment: I just saw that the link used $y$, $y'$, and $y''$ and thought that I could probably use something like that.